# How can I have cypress automation post a complete report once all the test are done

Tags: javascript, automation, cypress

Currently I am posting to Slack when the test fails. but I wanna be able to add the report at the end of the test as well. So when all the feature files are done and we reported all the broken tests. I wanna be able to report this as well

When cypress gets to run in command line `npm run cypress run` it generates the below test report after all the tests are done. how can I access that report and post it in slack? and also how can I send a message after all the tests are done and confirm the tests has been finished

> Spec                                              Tests  Passing
> Failing  Pending  Skipped
> ┌─────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
> ├────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┤
> │ ✔ 176.feature 00:31 1 1 - - - │
> ├────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┤
> │ ✔ 185.feature 00:07 1 1 - - - │
> ├────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┤
> │ ✔ 186.feature 00:11 1 1 - - - │
> ├────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┤
> │ ✖ 187.feature 06:26 7 6 1 - - │
> ├────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┤
> │ ✖ 194.feature 03:29 1 - 1 - - │
> ├────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┤
> │ ✔ 199.feature 00:34 1 1 - - - │
> ├────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┤
> │ ✔ 200.feature 00:34 1 1 - - - │
> ├────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┤
> │ ✔ 201.feature 00:30 1 1 - - - │
> ├────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┤
> │ ✔ 203.feature 01:00 1 1 - - - │
> ├────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┤
> │ ✔ 205.feature 01:04 1 1 - - - │
> ├────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┤
> │ ✖ 227.feature 01:47 1 - 1 - - │
> ──────────────────────────────────────┘ ✖ 3 of 29 failed (10%) 34:22
> 40 37 3 - -

This is what I have right now. Every test that finishes it sends a message that it has finished the test `:checkered_flag: :checkered_flag:`. I only want this to show when all the tests and feature files are done. kind of as last message before programs stop. I also need to include the above report in there . I am not sure how I can access that above report .this is my support/index.js file

```
after(() => {
  let reportedTests;
  let url = Cypress.env('SLACK_WEBHOOK_URL'); 
  let time = new Date().toLocaleString();
  const findTests = (suite) => {
    suite.tests.forEach((test) => {
      if (test.state === "failed" && test._retries >= 3) {
        reportedTests = {

          "attachments": [
            {
              "color": "#FF0000",
              "fields": [
                {
                  "title": "The following test has failed ",
                  "value": test.title,
                  "short": true,
                },
              ],
            },
          ],
        };
        cy.request({
          method: "POST",
          url: url,
          followRedirect: false,
          headers: {
            "Content-Type": "application/json",
          },
          body: reportedTests
        });
      }
    });
    if (suite.suites.length < 1) {
//I need this to only happen at the end when all the tests are done and give me the above report
  reportedTests = {
    "text": "======  :checkered_flag: :checkered_flag: ==== " + time,
  };
  cy.request({
    method: "POST",
    url: url,
    followRedirect: false,
    headers: {
      "Content-Type": "application/json",
    },
    body: reportedTests
  });
      return;
    }
    suite.suites.forEach((nestedSuite) => {
      findTests(nestedSuite);
    });
  };
  cy.state("runnable").parent.suites.forEach((suite) => {
    findTests(suite);
  });
 
});
```

Comment: Please clarify what is going wrong. The code looks pretty sophisticated, and should work. ***" it posts everything for success"*** - what does that mean?

Comment: @MarionMorrison When you run `npm run cypress run' in command line runs the entire test suits, and as the results it generates a report, the one that you can see in the original quesiton it .so right now, I post to slack when the test case fails. once everything is finished, I want to post that report into slack as well. I need to see where that generates from. Or how I can send a message and say all the test suits have finished